# RX: Execute an action when a subscription is started or disposed?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I would like to keep track of the number of active subscriptions to my IObservable ?
I thought I could implement this by incrementing / decrementing a counter whenever "someone" calls Subscribe / Dispose.

How can I do that ?
Or is there a better way of doing it ?

It seems to be done by RefCount internally but the subscriptions counter is not exposed.

Thanks

Comment: yeah, thought it would be easy to unsub in onComplete but it isn't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by wrapping your Observable in Observable.Create:

```
IObservable<string> myObs;

var returnObservable = Observable.Create<string>(subj => {

    // TODO: Write code to do stuff on Sub

    var disp = myObs.Subscribe(subj);

    return Disposable.Create(() => {
        disp.Dispose();

        // TODO: Write code to do stuff in unsub.
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `lock` or `InterLocked` to ensure thread safety in the "TODO" sections.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks that was what I needed.
This can be turned into an operator as follows:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> OnSubscribe<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Action onSubscribe, Action onDispose)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<TSource>(observer =>
            {
                onSubscribe?.Invoke();
                var subscription = source.Subscribe(observer);
                return () =>
                {
                    subscription.Dispose();
                    onDispose?.Invoke();
                };
            });
}
```